# edit textbox value in magento

Tags: php, magento

I am new in magento extension devlopment.

I have to change my textbox value when i am click on button, in magento. Following are some important part of my code.
when this same I try in simple PHP it works so why not in magento?

My script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText2(){
            var street = document.getElementById('street_1').value;
            var city=document.getElementById('city').value;
            var state=document.getElementById('region').value;       
            var zip=document.getElementById('zip').value;       
            var newcity=document.getElementById('newcity').value;
            document.getElementById('city').innerHTML=newcity;
            return confirm(city);              
            return true;
    }
   </script>
```

This is button code:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="city" />
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my phtml code:

```
<input type="text" value="xyz" id="newcity">
<input type="submit" name="truemagentosubmit" value="This will real submit the form" onclick='changeText2()'/>
```

When I am click on submit button it dosent change the value of textbox whose id is city.

please give me some suggestion on this code. How can I resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 document.getElementById('city').innerHTML=;
```

To:

```
 document.getElementById('city').value=newcity;
```

and try